# TeamCity Visual Studio Build doesn't find package reference packages

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

I have a Teamy City Build Server and wanted to migrate my solution piece by piece to Package Reference. Unfortunately it seems that it doesn't find the references / packages for those project I already moved or reacreated with package reference. The packages are restored correctly as I see them in the global .nuget\packages folder. Also I can build locally without any issues. 
Funny enough, I have some other smaller projects which do work correctly with package reference on teamcity.

TeamCity Version: 2019.2
NuGet: 5.4

I also tried to add a .NET CLI Task with a restore command, but that didn't change anything aswell.

NuGet Installer Step:
[image]

dotnet restore step:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I create a new pipeline and reconfigured all the steps from scratch instead of copy an existing pipline and now it works. seems there was some issue somewhere attached to those existing pipelines.

Comment: Do you mean you just created a new build configuration? Or was it more than that?

Comment: also did not work for me. i've created a new build config from scratch, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

After an entire day of trying to fix this problem I finally found the cause.

In the parameters of the build configuration in TeamCity there was a parameter called "system.VisualStudioVersion" with its value set to "11.0". I changed the value to "16.0", and this fixed the problem for me.

This might explain the solution of NPadrutt, assuming he had the variable set in that particular build configuration. Recreating his build configuration would then result in a new build configuration without the bad parameter, fixing the problem for him. But in my situation the parameter was inherited from the root project, so recreating the build configuration wouldn't have fixed it for me.

Comment: where did you add this setting?

Comment: thats probably not it... i dont have this parameter set, and im still facing this issue.